# SQL Server Management Studio Query Stop/Exit

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Apologies if this has been asked before, but the case is not so usual.

I work with a lot with a single `.sql` file with many helper queries in it, example:

```
select * from elmah_error order by timeutc desc;
select * from orders order by timeutc desc;
```

I want to prevent whole file execution with F5 so that only "selection" is executed upon pressing F5.

I looked around SQL Server Management Studio for any setting that could prevent "full file execution" and couldn't find any.

Is there and `EXIT/BREAK/GOTOTOP` T-SQL command I could use at the top of each file?

```
stop;

select * from elmah_error order by timeutc desc;
select * from orders order by timeutc desc;
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not have any batches executing in your file but only sql statements i.e Sql Statements are not separated with `GO`, you can modify your file using `GOTO` and skip the statement you do not want to be executed.

But if you do have sql statement in separate batches then this will not work.

```
/* Execute the following Statements */

PRINT 'Statement 1 executed'
PRINT 'Statement 2 executed'

GOTO SKIP_3;   --<-- this will skip the statement 3 and will jump to "SKIP_3: Label" 

/* Skip Statement 3 */
PRINT 'Statement 3 executed'

SKIP_3:                   
PRINT 'Statement 4 executed'

GOTO END_EXIT;          --<-- Stop script execution here and jump to end

/* Execute Statement 5 and 6 */
PRINT 'Statement 5 executed'
PRINT 'Statement 6 executed'

END_EXIT:
```

**Result**

```
Statement 1 executed
Statement 2 executed
Statement 4 executed
```